# benchmark/profiling maximum users can support on web application

Tags: spring, tomcat, profiling, performance-testing

any easy to use utility/tool/profiler/benchmark that able to test what is the maximum users a web application able to support by analyzing session size , cpu speed, memory size..etc and 'PREDICT' when server is overpacked/overloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) is a simple-to-use system that fires requests to your web server. You can try different numbers of users (i.e. sessions) with different numbers or types of requests. You could try increasing the number of users until the latency/speed of your system is unsatisfactorily slow.